# Selenium bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, matrix, selenium-ide

I'd like to know how to get the values from a bi-dimensional array in Selenium.
I have a file called resources.js, where I create the arrays and access it in Selenium, here is the array:

[image]

This array must have 4 columns and n numbers of lines.
How do I store the values of the 4 columns in variables? (it would be good to do it in a WHILE loop, to store/show the values from all rows if possible)

This is what I've tried and failed miserably:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like more of a JavaScript question than a Selenium question. The way to access multi-dimensional arrays in JS is like: Test[array_index][item_in_array_index].

So if you were trying to get the value 'name1', it would be Test[0][0].